# How to deploy Camunda BPM to Tomcat in Jelastic

Tags: tomcat7, bpmn, jelastic, camunda

I would like to setup Camunda-BPM in a Tomcat 7 running on [Jelastic](http://www.jelastic.com). I followed the [instructions](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/installation-guide/tomcat/#bpm-platform-install-the-platform-on-a-vanilla-tomcat).
The problem now is that Jelastic does not allow to add the file bpm-platform.xml into the catalina-home/conf directory. So when I start the tomcat I get

```
    ...
    Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: /opt/tomcat/conf/bpm-platform.xml does not exist. This file is necessary for deploying the camunda BPM platform
```

Can someone please give me a hint where I can place bpm-platform.xml so that the BPM engine starts?

Answer (score 1):

The directory you're looking for is labelled as 'server' in the Jelastic dashboard - but sadly you cannot upload new files to this directory via the dashboard (only edit the existing ones).

However, you can write to this directory via FTP (http://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support), so you should be able to add the file that way.

If you are just using a trial account at the moment, you may need to seek assistance from your hosting provider to add the file there for you manually from their side (since trial accounts do not have public IP, so can't use FTP).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! This solved the problem. I could manage to upload the file as described in the link via ftp. Now Camunda engine is working fine in Jelastic.